# При удалении заказа удаляются и продукты Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Есть класс `Order` и класс `Product`. Не получается удалить `Order`, без удаления `Product` из базы. То есть вначале создаётся `Product`, хранится в отдельной таблице. Потом создаётся заказ и product передаётся в `Order`. При удалении `Order` удаляется и `Product` из базы(только те, что были в `Order`)

Как удалить `Order` и при этом сохранить объекты `Product`? Пытался поместить в отдельный лист список `Product` и после удаления `Order` заново сохранить в базе. Выдаёт ошибку типа `org.hibernate.ObjectDeletedException: deleted instance passed to merge: [startApp.entities.Product#<null>]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.ObjectDeletedException: deleted instance passed to merge: [startApp.entities.Product#<null>]`

`Order.java`

```
@Data
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "order_db")
public class Order {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "id")
private long id;

@Column(name = "order_price")
private double orderPrice;

@Column(name = "status")
private String status;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="user_id")
private User user;

@OneToMany(
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = false
)
private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

`Product.java`

```
@Data
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "product_id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "product_name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "price")
    private double price;

    @Column(name = "img")
    private String img;

    @Column(name = "inOrder")
    private boolean inOrder = false;
}
```

Comment: Уберите cascade = CascadeType.ALL и все решиться. Вы каскадно все связанное удаляете с этим.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Убрал `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` (связывает таблицы, потому и всё удаляет) и всё заработало.
Спасибо [Andrii Torzhkov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/302329/andrii-torzhkov) за ответ

Comment: а отмечать ответ решением кто будет?)